# I want program to close if number is negative but it closes even if the number is positive

Tags: c#

So basically I'm coding a little program that calculates the area of a triangle. However, I get the warning that the number is negative even when I type in positive number. It worked before I added the negative number checking. Anyone can help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double num;
        Console.WriteLine("Base length: ");
        num = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (num < 0 );
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number cannot be negative");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        double num2;
        Console.WriteLine("Height: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (num2 < 0) ;
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number cannot be negative");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        double x = num;
        double y = num2;
        Console.WriteLine("Base is " + x + "cm long, and the height is " + y + "cm");
        Console.WriteLine("1/2*" + x + "*" + y);
        Console.WriteLine("The area is " + 0.5*x*y + "square cm.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the semicolons from your `if` statements.

```
if (num2 < 0) ;
```

should be

```
if (num2 < 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :D

Comment: You're welcome.  Please choose this as the accepted answer if you're happy with it.

Comment: 11 upvotes? Really?? Sockpuppets anyone???

Comment: No one's more surprised than me.  I've had tougher answers get no votes.  Not sure why people seem to like this one.  (No sockpuppets).